# Компиляция x86 из под x64: skipping incompatible when searching for -lmysqlclient

Tags: mysql, gcc, mariadb, makefile, кросс-компиляция

Пытаюсь из под Debian(x64) скомпилировать код для целевой платформы x86:

> /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible
>   //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so when searching for
>   -lmysqlclient /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

На компьютере отсутствуют библиотеки для x86 `MariaDBClient(mysqlclient)`, только для x64, попытки установить для x86 не дали результата - не дает установить пакет из-за архитектуры x64. В связи с чем немного смущен. Как в этих случаях поступают?

UPD

Сейчас у меня проблема такая: у меня настроена multiarch, при установке нужного мне пакета **libmariadbclient-dev:i386** мне предлагается удалить **libmariadbclient-dev:amd64**. Как установить для **i386**, не удаляя для **amd64**?

Comment: >>попытки установить для x86 не дали результата - не дает установить пакет из-за архитектуры x64<< — как именно пытался установить? в современном debian'е мультиарч поддерживается практически полноценно...

Comment: @Fat-Zer `dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so` , выяснил что пакет который на который ссылается эта библиотека libmariadbclient-dev-compat:amd64, далее начал искать на [https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libmariadbclient-dev-compat], в списке архитектур подходит, как я понимаю, только i386, (мне нужна компиляция для i686), скачал .deb пакет с i386, вот его не получилось поставить.

Answer (score 2):

Для установки на одну машину пакетов различных архитектур в debian используется такая штука, как [multiarch](https://wiki.debian.org/ru/Multiarch/HOWTO). Для этого нужно сказать о новой архитектуре `dpkg`:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Далее пакеты можно устанавливать из репозитариев как обычно, указав архитектуру через двоеточие:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install libmariadbclient-dev-compat:i386
```

---

> Сейчас у меня проблема такая: у меня настроена multiarch, при установке нужного мне пакета **libmariadbclient-dev:i386** мне предлагается удалить **libmariadbclient-dev:amd64**. Как установить для **i386**, не удаляя для **amd64**?

Судя по всему, полноценная поддержки сборки с помощью multiarch под другие архитектуры пока нет, за подробностями попыток реализации такого подхода см. [MultiarchCross](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchCross).

В качестве альтернативы можно воспользоваться cross-[chroot](https://wiki.debian.org/chroot)'ом, где все необходимые пакеты устанавливаются в отдельный префикс, если в двух словах, то последовательность действий примерно следующая:

```
MY_CHROOT=/path/to/chroot/stretch-i386
debootstrap --arch i386 stretch "$MY_CHROOT"
cp -r my-project "$MY_CHROOT"/
mount -o bind /dev "$MY_CHROOT"/dev
mount -t proc none "$MY_CHROOT"/proc
chroot "$MY_CHROOT"
apt-get update
apt-get install libmariadbclient-dev-compat
cd my-project && make
```

Comment: Я выяснил какие библиотеки мне нужны, на данный момент у меня установлена нужная, но, мне одновременно нужны в системе `default-libmysqlclient-dev:amd64 default-libmysqlclient-dev:i386`. Но при установке одна, удаляет другую. Как их установить вместе, чтобы не конфликтовали?

Comment: при установке `default-libmysqlclient-dev:i386' удаляются 'default-libmysqlclient-dev:amd64`.

Comment: @infernalcucumber, добавил в ответ